# Finite vector space V,W so is L(V,W)

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

> Preceding example:
>
> If V,W are vector spaces then $Map\left ( V,W \right )$ is an infinite dimensional vector space with operation defined by $\left ( f+g \right )\left ( v \right ):=f\left ( v \right )+g\left ( v \right )$
>    and
>   $ \left ( \alpha f \right )\left ( v \right ):=\alpha f\left ( v \right )$.
>   The linear map $L\left ( V,W \right )$ form a subspace of Map$\left ( V,W \right )$

I believe the question below is preceded by this example:

> Prove that if V,W are finite dimensional then so is $L\left ( V,W \right )$.

Here's my attempt:

Let V,W be finite dimension n.
Hence, V,W contains a set of n linearly independent vectors but no n+1 linearly independent vectors.

Let $L:V\rightarrow W$

with 
$
\left ( f+q \right )\left ( v \right ):=f\left ( v \right )+g\left ( v \right )$
and
$\left ( \alpha f \right )\left ( v \right ):=\alpha f\left ( v \right )$

Seemingly, I am unable to progress forward.

Hints are appreciated

Comment: I suppose $Map(V,W)$ means the set of all functions from V to W. I don't think $Map(V,W)$ is necessarily infinite-dimensional. For example, if V and W are both zero vector spaces, then $Map(V,W)$ has only one element, and is a zero-dimensional vector space.

Comment: What does L(V,W) means?

Comment: $L(V,W)$ is the set of all linear transformations from V to W.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When first learning about function structures like your $L(V,W)$, I felt it useful to think of matrices.

Remember **all** linear transformations $T:V\to W$ where $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional have matrix representations. Once you fix bases, you can find a matrix $M$ such that $T(x) = Mx$. If $T$ sends $n-$dimensional vectors to $m-$dimensional vectors then the size of $M$ is size $m\times n$. Specifically, $\dim(L(V,W)) = \dim(M_{m\times n}) = nm$.

So here's what you do. Fix bases $B_V$ and $B_W$ for $V,W$ respectively (you can even use a coordinate transformation to work in $R^k$ if you wish). Then count the number of transformations by counting the number of ways to map $B_V$ to $B_W$. Linear transformations are determined by what they do to a basis.

Comment: By fixing a bases, do you mean by "Let B={v_{1},...v_{n}}"?
The last time I touched LA was 2 years ago...

Comment: Here's what I have thus far:
Let $B_{V}={\bar{v}_{1},...,\bar{v}_{n}}$ and 
$B_{W}={\bar{w}_{1},...,\bar{w}_{m}}$.
Respectively, every vectors in V,W can be expressed as a linear combination of the span of the set of basis.

Comment: I may have mislead you what I said. Apologies. Each of the $T(v_i)'s$ must be sent to a linear combination of the $w_j$'s. i.e. $T(v_i) = x_{i1}w_1 + \cdots x_{im}w_m$. You want to count so as to get linearly independent maps each time. So its not $m\cdot m \cdot m...$. The easiest way to get linearly independent maps is to choose $1$'s or $0$'s for the coefficients. For the first map, choose $x_{11}=1$, and all other $x_{ij}=0$. Second map, $x_{12}=1$ rest $0$, etc. In the end you'll have one simple, linearly independent map for each pair $(i,j)$.

Comment: I don't understand...
What exactly is it we want to achieve with LI maps? I thought we want n, m linearly independent vectors in V and W respectively.
Sorry..it isn't at all clear to me what we are attempting to show. I'm getting caught in the details without the big picture.

Comment: You're constructing a basis for $L(V,W)$. Remember size of a basis = dimension, and a basis is any maximum set of linearly independent vectors (maps in this case).

Comment: I agree with your first sentence above. Every linear map can be expressed as a matrix representation. And yes, size of basis = size of dimensions.

Comment: After fixing bases you get a matrix representation:$$\begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ x_{m1} & x_{m2} & \cdots & x_{mn}\end{pmatrix}$$
The first column is formed of the coefficients of $T(v_1) = x_{11}w_1 + \cdots x_{1m}w_m$. You can see the matrices $E_{ij}$ where entry $(i,j)$ is $1$ and all others are zero. So $mn$ linearly independent matrices. You can choose it to be $5$ if you want, or some other odd coefficients that make linearly independent matrices but why? You just want them to be linearly independent and so $1,0$ suffices.

Comment: Its basically 1 across the diagonal. I do not understand the mn linearly independent matrices though. It could be my rusty understanding of the definition and notation.

Comment: No, for example $$L(\mathbb R^2, \mathbb R^2) \simeq M_{2\times 2}$$ where $$M_{2\times 2} \simeq \text{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Comment: I'll give it more thoughts. Will give you an upvote. Its consuming too much time and work is piling.

Comment: i submitted that comment too soon, i was editing

Comment: I would really prefer to show this question in terms of isomorphism(AA).
LA is my weakest area in mathematics.

Comment: Vector spaces and their generalizations (e.g. modules) are one of the most important structures in algebra. The isomorphism is simple. If $T(v_i) = \sum_{j=1}^m x_{ij} w_j$ then $\Phi: L(V,W) \to M_{m\times n}$ given by $$\Phi(T) = \begin{pmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1n}\\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ x_{m1} & x_{m2} & \cdots & x_{mn}\end{pmatrix}$$ is the isomorphism.

Comment: Two things then: If L is a homomorphism(and a linear map indeed is), then I could show that a bijection exists from V to W.
Or, that the Kernel of the map L is trivial and we are done.

Comment: Correct. The kernel is the map where all $x_{ij}=0$. So any vector $v=\sum a_i v_i \mapsto 0w_1 + 0w_2 + ... + 0w_m = 0$. Since the dimensions are the same, it must be an isom. of vector spaces.

Answer (score -1):

In case the following words make sense:

The category of finite-dimensional vector spaces over a field $k$ is symmetric monoidal closed and hence enriched over itself.